# location.href refreshes instead of redirecting

Tags: javascript

I'm making a javascript game and once the user finished the game, the user will enter their initials and hit submit. Once they hit submit, it'll redirect them to a new page (end.html). I'm not sure if I've set up my click event incorrectly or I'm using the wrong location.href. But, when I hit the submit button, it brings the user back to the start screen(index.html), instead of the end (highscore) page.

The script tag is located on the bottom of the HTML pages, tags are correctly named. I tried the DOMContentLoaded function and that didn't seem to work. If I need to provide more of my code, please let me know.

here's the js snippet

```
submitScore.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var initials = document.getElementById("initials").value;
  // calling highscore page function
  endPage(initials, time);
});


function endPage(inits, scores) {
  var userData = {
    inits: inits,
    scores: scores
  };
  highscores.push(userData);
  
  localStorage.setItem("userData", JSON.stringify(highscores));
  location.href = "end.html"
}
```

Comment: Why `location.assign` instead of `location.href` or [`Location.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace)?

Comment: location.assign is a function and you are assigning it a value. Try: `location.assign('yourUrl/end.html');`

Comment: whoops. Excuse my mistake. I originally had location.href and that didn't work. Then I tried location.assign.

Comment: replace works..

Comment: submit submits the page....

Comment: That didn't work either... I might have a bug in my code ://

Comment: `submitScore.addEventListener("click", function (evt) { evt.preventDefault();`

Comment: YESSS! I needed the event.preventDefault() Thanks so much!!

Comment: change `location.href="end.html"` to `window.location.replace(`${location.origin}/end.html`);`

Answer (score 1):

I personally have never used `location.assign` - have you tried `location.replace()`?

```js
submitScore.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var initials = document.getElementById("initials").value;
  // calling highscore page function
  endPage(initials, time);
});


function endPage(inits, scores) {
  var userData = {
    inits: inits,
    scores: scores
  };
  highscores.push(userData);
  
  localStorage.setItem("userData", JSON.stringify(highscores));
  location.replace(`${location.origin}/end.html`); 
  // get base url and append 'end.html'
}
```

EDIT [for others confused]: Actual bug was that the button was being submitted - bravo `epascarello` for this code:

```js
submitScore.addEventListener("click", function (evt) { 
    evt.preventDefault(); // prevent default behaviour of event
```

Comment: My mistake. I originally had location.href where location.assign is, just to test it. Both do not work. But I'll try your solution!

Comment: No worries, I noticed your mistake haha ;) let me know how it goes!

Comment: I tried your solution, and that didn't work either... I may have a bug somewhere in my js file. ://